# How to structure entities of nested one to one relationships so that you can get all in one query in Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

I have entity for user.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.ForeignKey;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Address.class, parentColumns = "addressId", childColumns = "fk_addressId", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Company.class, parentColumns = "companyId", childColumns = "fk_companyId", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
})
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int userId;

    public String name;
    public String username;
    public String email;


    public int fk_addressId;
    public String phone;
    public String website;
    public int fk_companyId;

    public User(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String username, @NonNull String email, int fk_addressId,
                @NonNull String phone, @NonNull String website, int fk_companyId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.fk_addressId = fk_addressId;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.website = website;
        this.fk_companyId = fk_companyId;
    }
}
```

The user has two foreign keys referring to Address and Company entities. It's one-to-one relationship between user and Address, and between User and Company.

And the Address has a foreign key referring to Geo (used for geolocation). There's a one-to-one relationship between Address and Geo.

I want to get the User with its Address, Geo, and Company information in one query using Room in Android.

**How should I build the relational classes to do that?**

There's information in this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#java

But in this case User entity has two foreign keys one referring to Address and other to Company. (And Address is referring to Geo).

**How should I build the relational classes to get User with Address, Geo and Company information in one query using Room in Android?**

Here's the address entity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.ForeignKey;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Geo.class, parentColumns = "geoId", childColumns = "fk_geoId", onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
})
public class Address {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int addressId;

    public String street;
    public String suite;
    public String city;
    public String zipCode;

    public int fk_geoId;

    public Address(@NonNull String street, @NonNull String suite, @NonNull String city,
                   @NonNull String zipCode, int fk_geoId) {
        this.street = street;
        this.suite = suite;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.fk_geoId = fk_geoId;
    }
}
```

Here's Geo entity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class Geo {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int geoId;
    
    public double lat;
    public double lng;

    public Geo(@NonNull double lat, @NonNull double lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

And here's the company entity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class Company {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int companyId;

    public String name;
    public String catchPhrase;
    public String bs;

    public Company(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String catchPhrase, @NonNull String bs) {
        this.name = name;
        this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}
```

**How should I build the relational classes to get User with Address, Geo and Company information in one query using Room in Android?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd suggest changing some columns names to make them unique so for example

- change `name` in the `Company` class/entity to `companyName`

  - this is to disambiguate it from `name` in the `User` class/entity
  - an alternative would be to utilise the `@Embedded`'s `prefix` parameter e.g. `@Embedded(prefix = "cmpny_")` in the POJO used for combining (see UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo below)

So `Company` could be :-

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int companyId;

    public String companyName;
    public String catchPhrase;
    public String bs;

    public Company(@NonNull String companyName, @NonNull String catchPhrase, @NonNull String bs) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}
```

Second, you don't really need separate tables for one to one relationships, the way you have things the relations can be 1 to many (1 company can have many users, 1 address can have many users and 1 geo can have many addresses). See additional at the end of the answer.

Next add a class (POJO) for getting all of the combined data e.g. `UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo`. With this method `JOIN`s will be used in the Query so simply Embed all of the Entities (User,Company,Address and Geo) as per :-

```
public class UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo {

    @Embedded
    User user;
    @Embedded
    Company company;
    @Embedded
    Address address;
    @Embedded
    Geo geo;

    public UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo(){}

}
```

As previously stated JOINS in the query will be used to build the relationships, so to a/the Dao add the following :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user JOIN company ON user.fk_companyId = companyId JOIN address ON user.fk_addressId = address.addressId JOIN geo ON address.fk_geoId = geo.geoId")
List<UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo> getUserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo();
```

You can then utilise the getUserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo() to get all users with their company, address and geo.

**working Example**

using the above and then the following :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String TAG = "MYDBINFO";
    MyDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,MyDatabase.class,"mydb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        dao = db.getAllDao();
        int geo1Id = (int) dao.insertGeo(new Geo(52.5,72.3));
        int geo2Id = (int) dao.insertGeo(new Geo(33.3,66.6));
        int address1Id = (int) dao.insertAddress(new Address("Street1","suite1","city1","1234",geo1Id));
        int address2Id = (int) dao.insertAddress(new Address("Street2","Suite2","City2","4321",geo2Id));
        int company1Id = (int) dao.insertCompany(new Company("Company1","Catchphrase1","bs1"));
        int company2Id = (int) dao.insertCompany(new Company("Company2","Catchphrase2","bs2"));
        int user1 = (int) dao.insertUser(new User("Name1","UserName1","Email1",address1Id,"Phone1","Website1",company1Id));
        int user2 = (int) dao.insertUser(new User("Name2","UserName2","Email1",address2Id,"Phone2","Website2",company2Id));
        List<UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo> userWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeos = dao.getUserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo();
        for(UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo userWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo : userWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeos) {
            LogUserWithCompanyWithAddress(userWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo);
        }
    }

    private void LogUserWithCompanyWithAddress(UserWithCompanyWithAddressWithGeo uwcwa) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "User-Name = " + uwcwa.user.name +
                        " User-Email = " + uwcwa.user.email +
                        "\n\tCompany - Name = " + uwcwa.company.companyName + " Company - Catchphrase = " + uwcwa.company.catchPhrase +
                        "\n\tAddress - Street = " + uwcwa.address.street + " Address - City = " + uwcwa.address.city +
                        "\n\t\tGeo - Lat = " + uwcwa.geo.lat + " Geo - Long = " + uwcwa.geo.lng
        );
    }
}
```

- the above is just for testing and is not designed to be rerun.
- it also runs on the main thread for convenience and brevity.

The result in the Log (first run) :-

```
2021-04-08 06:58:54.635 D/MYDBINFO: User-Name = Name1 User-Email = Email1
        Company - Name = Company1 Company - Catchphrase = Catchphrase1
        Address - Street = Street1 Address - City = city1
            Geo - Lat = 52.5 Geo - Long = 72.3
2021-04-08 06:58:54.636 D/MYDBINFO: User-Name = Name2 User-Email = Email1
        Company - Name = Company2 Company - Catchphrase = Catchphrase2
        Address - Street = Street2 Address - City = City2
            Geo - Lat = 33.3 Geo - Long = 66.6
```

**Additional**

Re 1-Many relationships consider the following that has been added to the activity used for testing (after the other inserts but before the extract)

```
int userx = (int) dao.insertUser(new User("NameX","UserX","EmailX",address1Id,"PhoneX","WebsiteX",company2Id));
```

- This is using the same address as User1 and the company as per User2. Running results in

:-

```
2021-04-08 07:34:59.851 12295-12295/a.a.so66992840javaroomonetoones D/MYDBINFO: User-Name = Name1 User-Email = Email1
        Company - Name = Company1 Company - Catchphrase = Catchphrase1
        Address - Street = Street1 Address - City = city1
            Geo - Lat = 52.5 Geo - Long = 72.3
2021-04-08 07:34:59.851 12295-12295/a.a.so66992840javaroomonetoones D/MYDBINFO: User-Name = Name2 User-Email = Email1
        Company - Name = Company2 Company - Catchphrase = Catchphrase2
        Address - Street = Street2 Address - City = City2
            Geo - Lat = 33.3 Geo - Long = 66.6
2021-04-08 07:34:59.851 12295-12295/a.a.so66992840javaroomonetoones D/MYDBINFO: User-Name = NameX User-Email = EmailX
        Company - Name = Company2 Company - Catchphrase = Catchphrase2
        Address - Street = Street1 Address - City = city1
            Geo - Lat = 52.5 Geo - Long = 72.3
```

**Alternative Approach** - Using @Relation

When Embedding Entities as per the initial approach the Query requires the use of JOIN's. However, you can avoid, using JOIN's and let room effectively build the JOIN's by using @Relation annotations. However, when using @Relation a List/array of the Embedded entity is retrieved.

It appears that for a 3 level hierarchy (user -> Address - Geo) that you need 2 levels of @Relation and thus 2 POJO classes.

The first (lowest in the hierarchy) (Address-Geo) could be **AddressWithGeo** :-

```
public class AddressWithGeo {

    @Embedded
    Address address;
    @Relation(entity = Geo.class,entityColumn = "geoId",parentColumn = "fk_geoId")
    List<Geo> geos;

    public AddressWithGeo(){}
}
```

The Second (Use-> Address and User -> Company) could be **UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo** :-

```
public class UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo {
    @Embedded
    User user;
    @Relation(entity = Company.class,entityColumn = "companyId",parentColumn = "fk_companyId")
    List<Company> company;
    @Relation(entity = Address.class,entityColumn = "addressId",parentColumn = "fk_addressId")
    List<AddressWithGeo> addressWithGeos;

    public UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo(){}
}
```

- i.e. instead of @Embedded @Relation is used for the lower level classes,
- also note that as AddressWithGeo is not an entity but a POJO the relationship is to the Address table.

To use the above you need a Dao @Query for at least the higher level. However the following are @Queries for both (thus allowing extraction of Addresses with the Geo) :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM address")
List<AddressWithGeo> getAddressWithGeos();
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
List<UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo> getUserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo();
```

The following was added to **MainActivity** :-

```
    List<AddressWithGeo> addressWithGeos = dao.getAddressWithGeos(); // shows that AddressWithGeo can be used on it's own
    List<UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo> userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeos = dao.getUserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo();
    for (UserWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo: userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeos) {
        logUser(userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo.user);
        for(Company cmpny: userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo.company) {
            logCompany(cmpny);
        }
        for(AddressWithGeo awg: userWithCompanyWithAddressAndGeo.addressWithGeos) {
            logAddress(awg.address);
            for(Geo geo: awg.geos) {
                logGeo(geo);
            }
        }
    }
```

- Note looping through the lists (if you are 100% sure that at least one and only one  Company, Address and/or Geo will exist then you could access element 0 without looping through the list).

Along with the following Methods (to make writing output to the log simpler) :-

```
private void logUser(User usr) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Name = " + usr.name + " Username = " + usr.username + " Email = " + usr.email + " Phone = " + usr.phone + " Website = " + usr.website);
}
private void logCompany(Company cmpny) {
    Log.d(TAG,"\tName = " + cmpny.companyName + " CatchPhrase = " + cmpny.catchPhrase + " BS = " + cmpny.bs);
}
private void logAddress(Address addr) {
    Log.d(TAG,"\tStreet = " + addr.street + " Suite = " + addr.suite + " City = " + addr.city + " Zipcode = " + addr.zipCode);
}
private void logGeo(Geo geo) {
    Log.d(TAG,"\t\t Lat = " + geo.lat + " Long = " + geo.lng);
}
```

The Result (in addition to the previous) when run being :-

```
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO: Name = Name1 Username = UserName1 Email = Email1 Phone = Phone1 Website = Website1
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO:     Name = Company1 CatchPhrase = Catchphrase1 BS = bs1
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO:     Street = Street1 Suite = suite1 City = city1 Zipcode = 1234
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO:          Lat = 52.5 Long = 72.3
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO: Name = Name2 Username = UserName2 Email = Email1 Phone = Phone2 Website = Website2
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO:     Name = Company2 CatchPhrase = Catchphrase2 BS = bs2
2021-04-08 18:26:04.595 D/MYDBINFO:     Street = Street2 Suite = Suite2 City = City2 Zipcode = 4321
2021-04-08 18:26:04.596 D/MYDBINFO:          Lat = 33.3 Long = 66.6
2021-04-08 18:26:04.596 D/MYDBINFO: Name = NameX Username = UserX Email = EmailX Phone = PhoneX Website = WebsiteX
2021-04-08 18:26:04.596 D/MYDBINFO:     Name = Company2 CatchPhrase = Catchphrase2 BS = bs2
2021-04-08 18:26:04.596 D/MYDBINFO:     Street = Street1 Suite = suite1 City = city1 Zipcode = 1234
2021-04-08 18:26:04.596 D/MYDBINFO:          Lat = 52.5 Long = 72.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

But in this link: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships it says: "Caution: Querying data with nested relationships requires Room to manipulate a large volume of data and can affect performance. Use as few nested relationships as possible in your queries.  "

So it's faster to use JOIN than using @Relation when querying nested relationships?

Comment: @Code88 I'd personally use Embedded's and JOIN's as I believe that in addition to the looped nature of `@Relation` there are also other restrictions such as WHERE clauses. There again from experiments I've undertaken Room itself, in comparison to stock android SQLite, affects performance.